Git rejected non-fast-forward
I have seen several posts in StackOverflow related to this issue, but yet I cannot find a solution:
Example of posts:

What does "Git push non-fast-forward updates were rejected" mean?
git pull says up-to-date but git push rejects non-fast forward
Never-ending GIT story - what am I doing wrong here?

I'm working with gitlab, in a branch where I'm the only user, and every single time I try to commit/push a change using Eclipse, I get the same error:

Things I have checked before trying to commit/push:

"git pull" returns: Already up to date.
"git status" returns: On branch main Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'. nothing to commit, working tree clean
"git remote -v" returns: origin  https://xxxx/yyyy.git (fetch) origin  https://xxxx/yyyy.git (push)
"gitk --all" returns (here you can see the monster tree this issue is creating):


Every merge shown in the tree contains:

This is my config:
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    puttykeyfile = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    push = HEAD:refs/heads/main
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
    rebase = false
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 893x435+104+104 227 196

Right after the error I do a git pull and it brings me the commit that introduced the error and a merge commit with 0 changes, in this spot I can actually push both commits and keep working. The next time I will have to commit/push changes the whole thing will repeat itself. The error will be shown, I will have to do a git pull after my commit, it will bring me the "ghost" merge with 0 changes and then I will be able to push both commits. This is the result of that pull:


The first commit is the one I tried to do.
The second commit is the one that magically appeared.

I have been using git with a project I own in github without issues for years, but since I have started to use gitlab at work I have the exact same issue with every single project we have, and we cannot find a solution to this (we have been using SVN for years so we are beginners in the GIT/gitlab world).

What do you get when you run git fetch --all? Why do you push main directly instead of using a MR workflow? Does it happen in fresh clones too? Is somebody else pushing to the same repo frequently?

I'm the only user so far. I tried executing that command, it returns nothing, so I assume everything is up to date. I'm pushing directly to main because I'm the only one pushing changes, what do you suggest to do instead?

Your description of "git pull outputs Already up to date" doesn't match your gitk history with lots merges. Either everything is up to date or you have to merge. Are you sure you are not merging? With the screenshot of gitk, when you run git push origin main:main it should tell you "everything up to date"

In recent versions of git (since about 2009), you can have different remotes for push and pull.  Can you put the output of git remote -v onto your question?

@knittl when I get the error shown in the post, the next thing I do is "pull", then it returns my previous commit and the merge with 0 changes, then it allows me to push. Is in this spot where everything is up to date, and the next commit/push will reproduce the issue reported here.

@AndyJ I just edited my post adding that info, it shows two URLs (one for fetch and one for push, but both URLs are the same).

Do you rebase or amend your commits often?

Do you have "Merge commit" as the merge method for MRs in gitlab? From your gitk graph, it looks like you're pushing your change, it's adding a new merge commit, you're making a new change locally and then having the pull the merge commit before you can push the new change where the cycle starts again.

push = HEAD:refs/heads/main looks fishy. You are always pushing the current branch to main, regardless of what the current branch is. So git checkout -b testbranch origin/main && git commit --allow-empty -m 'test commit' && git push will update main (and not create a new branch testbranch in your remote)

@user1686 I haven't done even one rebase or reset a commit in this project yet.

@maqjav you should not blindly run git pull. If you need to merge, you should first check why and what you need to merge. When you encounter the situation of a non-fast-forward, take a step back. Run git fetch, followed by gitk main...origin/main to show the local and remote commits. This should tell you what happened in the remote. You might be amending your commits locally, you could have set up a hook on the server which modifies your commit (unlikely, but not unheard of), your pipeline is creating new commits, or many other options.

@Holloway I'm going to ask the administrator. I don't manage our gitlab project so I don't have access to those settings. If I'm not misunderstanding you, gitlab is creating that merge commit not when I'm pushing my changes, if not when I'm commiting them, so when I do a commit/push, the flow is: I have everything up to date, I commit new changes, gitlab creates a new merge commit, I try to push the changes, but I cannot because gitlab has created that merge commit in between the operations, so that's why I have to do the pull before pushing my changes, is that right?

@knittl I tried to follow your steps. I just added a change in a file and commit/push. I got the error, so I did a git fetch instead, it returned nothing. Now I executed gitk main...origin/main and it shows in my local main branch the change I just commited, and in the remotes/origin/main branch the latest merge with 0 changes that appeared in my latest "pull" and that I pushed right after.

So there is in fact a commit on the remote that is not part of your local history. Who is the author and committer of said commit? (unfortunately, you have censored that important information from your question). What is the author and committer date of the commit? Does a new, different commit appear once you merged the commit and pushed again? If so, what author/commit information does that commit have?

@knittl I have edited my post and I have added a screenshot of the pull. In theory I'm the author of both commits, and the date/time is exactly the same, so maybe as Holloway was mentioning before, gitlab is creating that automatic commit automatically whenever I commit something to the remote branch?

It could be. But with the censored images it's really difficult to give a sensible answer. Furthermore, you haven't effectively answered my questions about the author/committer. You write "theoretically I'm the author of both commits", but I'm not asking about "theoretical" hypothesis, but actual practical answers. "Who is the author and committer of the commit on the remote" has a factual answer and doesn't need to be answered "theoretically".

@knittl The author of both commits is myself. I said in theory because I actually tried to do only one of them, the other one just showed up. Sorry for the confusion.

@maqjav if both commits have the same author, same committer, same timestamp, and same content – they are actually the same commit (and MUST have identical commit ids). In one way or the other, the commits are different. How do you conclude that there are no changes? The diff of a merge only shows resolved conflicts. When you encounter the problem the next time and you have verified with gitk main...origin/main that there are two commits, run git diff origin/main main to see the difference between your local commit and the remote commit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@knittl I'm actually leaving the office right now, so tomorrow when I come back I will try to commit a new change and see what the command diff generates. Using the gitlab interface I can check the content of every one of those merges, and all of them show 0 changes. I posted a screenshot in the main post, thats why I assumed there were not changes. Thank you very much for your help.

That only means that the merge didn't have any conflicts. Important is the difference between the two parents of the merge.

Finally we found the problem, thanks to @knittl for his patience.
The issue was that Egit was automatically checking the option "Amend (Edit previous comment)" for every commit instead of creating a new one.

Definetly a begginers mistake, as we are starting to work with Git we didn't even know what that option was (not even noticed it was checked for every commit). After unchecking it the "issue" is completely gone.
